# Signing Contents of RPM

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I have some SPEC files to build my rpms with rpmbuild.

As i understand, during rpmbuild, the source code is fetched, binaries are compiled, installed to buildroot and packaged as RPM.

Is there a way to sign the binaries during this process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See: https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#Signing-Packages

If you are using Mock, you can use the sign-plugin:
https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki/Plugin-Sign